# How to resolve a group name to gid both in OSX and Linux?

Tags: linux, osx, group

Is there a [short] piece of code to turn a symbolic group name (e.g. `staff`) into its numeric *group id* (e.g. `82`) ?

The code should work the same in OS X and GNU/Linux.

Comment: @downvoters I'm self-answering (perhaps too slowly for you) -- because the question is not as easy as it looks.

Comment: Does macOS not have `/etc/group`?

Comment: @terdon so you propose to directly parse `/etc/group`?.. Hmm well, now that I think about it, seems not that bad idea.

Comment: I haven't posted an answer since I don't have a mac to test it on, but doesn't this do exactly what you need without the complexity of python: `awk -F: -vgroup=1000 '$3==group{print $1}' /etc/group` ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the group name isn't present on a system?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python's `grp` module is [simple enough](https://docs.python.org/3/library/grp.html). As the core idea for starters:

```
import grp
print(grp.getgrnam("my_group_name").gr_gid)
```

However, a more robust solution took me longer:

```
echo $MYGROUPNAME | python -c 'import grp,sys; gn=sys.stdin.readline().strip(); [gid]=[g.gr_gid for g in grp.getgrall() if g.gr_name==gn][:1]; print(gid)'
```

First, it's written to work on both **python2 and python3**.

Second: it **does not use `grp.getgrnam()`**, but fetches all groups and does its own filtering. Why? Because `getgrnam()` didn't work at all on at least one Mac I tested.

Third: it **truncates multiple results**. Why? Because `grp.getgrall()` returned duplicates on an least one Gentoo I tested.

Finally: yes, non-existent group will throw a traceback. **Tweak to your own needs.**

---

*N.B.*
[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910096/command-to-get-groupid-of-a-group-name-in-mac-or-linux) offers a few bits, but it's been closed, doesn't accept new answers and cannot be migrated. So here you have a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on terdon's comment:

Linux (debian 12, bookworm):

```
bookworm$ export mygroupname=staff
bookworm$ awk -F: -v group=${mygroupname} '$1==group{print $3}' /etc/group
50
```

MacOS Sonoma 14.4:

```
sonoma$ export mygroupname=staff
sonoma$ awk -F: -v group=${mygroupname} '$1==group{print $3}' /etc/group
20
```

Note that using uppercase variable names is generally discouraged to avoid potential clashes w/ system-wide identifiers.

Also note that this doesn't error if the group doesn't exist.

Comment: Decent one. A caveat to watch out: the `group` field in **`/etc/nsswitch.conf`** may contain more sources beyond `files` — in which case, `getgrnam()` will recognize more groups than recorded in the local `/etc/group` file. This happens in setups with user-group information centralized in NIS, LDAP, Samba, etc... thin-client-style places. On developer PCs these days, that's very rare, so parsing /etc/group might be good enough for that use-case.

Comment: Fair point - this is not the case in my work environment, so I didn't even ponder that.